# SOAP API cannot create multi-button radio group

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign SOAP API for envelope creation.

I am trying to add a pair of radio custom tabs but cannot get the envelope created while they are in the same radio group ... I get error:

> A Custom Tab is not Complete. A Custom Tab requires both a Name and a TabLabel. Radio tabs may only have one radio selected in a group.

This makes sense however the code generated from the WSDL (C#) does not have any means of setting one of the tabs to selected=true and the other to selected=false.

Here's a relevant snip from my C# code:

```
tabs.Add(new Tab 
{ 
    Type = TabTypeCode.Custom, 
    CustomTabType = Web.DocuSign.CustomTabType.Radio, 
    CustomTabTypeSpecified = true, 
    TabLabel = "Yes", 
    Name = "Yes", 
    RecipientID = signer1RecipientID, 
    DocumentID = documentID, 
    // TODO: how to set selected=true? 
    Value = "Yes", 
    CustomTabRadioGroupName = "RadioGroup1", 
    AnchorTabItem = new AnchorTab 
    { 
        AnchorTabString = "c1", 
        IgnoreIfNotPresent = true, 
        IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = true, 
        Unit = UnitTypeCode.Inches, 
        UnitSpecified = true, 
        XOffset = 0, 
        YOffset = 0 
    } 
}); 

tabs.Add(new Tab 
{ 
    Type = TabTypeCode.Custom, 
    CustomTabType = Web.DocuSign.CustomTabType.Radio, 
    CustomTabTypeSpecified = true, 
    TabLabel = "No", 
    Name = "No", 
    RecipientID = signer1RecipientID, 
    DocumentID = documentID, 
    Value = "No", 
    CustomTabRadioGroupName = "RadioGroup1", 
    // TODO: how to set selected=false? 
    AnchorTabItem = new AnchorTab 
    { 
        AnchorTabString = "c2", 
        IgnoreIfNotPresent = true, 
        IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = true, 
        Unit = UnitTypeCode.Inches, 
        UnitSpecified = true, 
        XOffset = 0, 
        YOffset = 0 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hope my answer helps. If not, can you please provide the raw XML request and response so we can see exactly what is going across the wire?

Comment: My ultimate goal was to have signatures conditional on which radio of a pair was clicked. It seems that the only one of the radios in a radio group can have a Value specified. It also seems that the label or the name of the radio tab functions as comparison value for the condition stated for the conditional signature.

Comment: Your original question did not include data nor attempts to use conditional field functionality. Can you please post your raw XML request? Have you tried using any of the Optional Conditional elements for your child Signature Tag? I.e. ConditionalParentLabel and ConditionalParentValue = 'on'? Please post your raw XML traces so I can help you further. Since you are now asking about conditional field functionality, this may need to be moved to a different question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set one of the radio buttons to default selected, you need to set the Value to 'X' not 'Yes.' And for radio buttons within a group only one may be selected at a time. See the Value element in the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Tab.htm).